# No tengo internet en mi maquina virtual anidada

Tags: windows

me gustaria que me ayuden con un problema.
Usando Hyper-V instale una maquina virtual con Windows Server 2019. Una vez hecho eso, active la virtualización anidada mediante un comando en Power Shell, logre instalar e iniciar una nueva maquina virtual dentro de la maquina virtual principal. El problema que tengo es que en la maquina virtual que esta dentro de la maquina virtual principal NO tiene internet, la principal maquina virtual si tiene internet mediante Bridge, pero para la otra ya no funciona ni por Bridge ni NAT. Tine alguna idea de porque o que debo configurar. Esta usando un de Microsfot Hyper-V Network Adapter como adaptador, asumo que es la que la maquina virtual principal tiene pero no nogra enviar red a la siguiente maquina virtual.

Intente usando NAT o otras configuraciones, incluso poniendo IPs manualmente pero no logra reconocer la re, el simbolo que tiene es el del signo de admiracion en amarillo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.